# Can't display two Javascript elements in Dreamweaver

Tags: javascript, dreamweaver

I'm a complete noob to Javascript integration, and am having an issue in Dreamweaver. I have two Javascript graphs that I want to display. Both work on their own on the page but I cannot get them to display together. I seem to remember having a similar issue many moons ago with a page that had two Javascript elements on it and they needed to called in a certain order:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.scruffybearddesign.co.uk/scripts/Chart.js"></script>
    </head>

<body>

    <div id="canvas-holder">
        <canvas id="chart-area" width="300" height="300"/>
    </div>


<script>

    var pieData = [
            {
                value: 300,
                color:"#F7464A",
                highlight: "#FF5A5E",
                label: "Red"
            },
            {
                value: 50,
                color: "#46BFBD",
                highlight: "#5AD3D1",
                label: "Green"
            },
            {
                value: 100,
                color: "#FDB45C",
                highlight: "#FFC870",
                label: "Yellow"
            },
            {
                value: 40,
                color: "#949FB1",
                highlight: "#A8B3C5",
                label: "Grey"
            },
            {
                value: 120,
                color: "#4D5360",
                highlight: "#616774",
                label: "Dark Grey"
            }

        ];

        window.onload = function(){
            var ctx = document.getElementById("chart-area").getContext("2d");
            window.myPie = new Chart(ctx).Pie(pieData);
        };



 </script>
 <div style="width: 50%">
        <canvas id="canvas" height="450" width="600"></canvas>
    </div>


<script>
var randomScalingFactor = function(){ return Math.round(Math.random()*100)};

var barChartData = {
    labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],
    datasets : [
        {
            fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
            highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
            highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data : [randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor()]
        },
        {
            fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
            highlightFill : "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
            highlightStroke : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            data : [randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor()]
        }
    ]

}
window.onload = function(){
    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
    window.myBar = new Chart(ctx).Bar(barChartData, {
        responsive : true
    });
}

</script>


</body>
```

So essentially I have two DIVs with Javascript code in, each DIV works fine on it's own but will not work together. Only the second graph will display. Both graphs call the same .JS file, could this be the issue?

Any insight would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onload` event will occur only one per page. That's why you are only seeing one, the other onload is being ignored.

To solve this, please set both functions to render the graph, in the same `onload` event

To solve this, use this code:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    var ctx = document.getElementById("chart-area").getContext("2d");
    window.myPie = new Chart(ctx).Pie(pieData);

    ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
    window.myBar = new Chart(ctx).Bar(barChartData, {
        responsive : true
    });
})
```

Comment: Adding to this answer, you can also bind multiple callbacks to the page load event by using `window.addEventListener('load', callback)` instead of `window.onload`

Comment: That makes sense. It only recognises the last 'onload' it receives. How would I edit this existing code to load graphs from the same 'onload'?

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you ever so much.